# MVC RouteConfig Setting Controller and Action attributes as parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, routes

I'm currently working on a course application site in MVC. I'm relatively new to MVC and I'm trying to get to grips with the RouteConfig file to achieve the aims of the information architecture and to avoid duplication.

I see this as an opportunity to have just three Controllers/views to handle the bulk of the logic:

View 1. Region/Country Select screen
View 2. Course Select screen
View 3. Course Detail and Application screen

The information architecture should work as follows:
{region}/{country}/{course}

1. The user selects a country/state where their course will operate from, the course country can exist in one of three geographic areas: AMER, EMEA and APAC
2. The user selects on of the courses available in their country/state.
   ~/AMER/USA/SignLanguage
   ~/EMEA/GBR/FirstAid
   ~/APAC/AUS/EmploymentLaw

   Each of the values for, region, country/state and course are db driven
3. The user view the course details, and applies for a class on the course.

Looking at the Default MapRoute and searching high and low, I'm struggling to find a way to introduce dynamic control and action source (operating as parameters), ensuring that I don't have to build three controls to handle region and a multitude of actions to accommodate each country being handled.

As the course is effectively an id anyway I'm pretty confident that that isn't a big issue.

I figure I could do something like this to handle the controller logic, but I think I would still have to produce several Controllers even in this scenario as well as the hundreds of actions.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Courses",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new {
    controller = "Region",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional
}
constraints: new {
    controller = @"^(AMER|EMEA|APAC).+/i"
});
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, what about doing this for the route:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{region}/{country}/{course}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Course", action = "Detail" }
  );
```

And Controller:

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
  // GET: Course
  public ActionResult Detail(string region, string country, string course)
  {
    //TODO: Validation
    var data = new Data
    {
      Region = region,
      Country = country,
      Course = course
    };

    return View(data);
  }
}
```

This worked on all three example URLs you gave. Then you can pass the validation logic over to service/repository/whatever to validate against your datastore of choice.  Then you don't need to do code changes when region/country/courses are added.

And to round out my example, here is the Data clasee:

```
public class Data
{
  public string Region { get; set; }
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public string Course { get; set; }
}
```

And View:

```
@model StackOverflowExamples.Mvc.Controllers.Data

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Details"; }

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Data</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region)</dd>

        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)</dd>

        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Course)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Course)</dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```